# IF(ISERROR combined with (Mod(Month

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have a formula that matches a start month to a horizontal calendar range. This is the formula:
=IF($I$17>=$F18,IF(MOD(MONTH($I$17)-MONTH($F18),$D18)=0,$E18,0),0)

When the match is found it takes a defined value and enters the value in that month. It also then extrapolate the same value every n number of months. This n number of months is defined.This is what the result looks like for the above formula[Pay $375 every 2nd month starting in Nov 18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RcAm.png)

The problem I can't fix is when the "Pay every # months" is blank the result is #DIV/0!. [The month frequency is blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUMEv.png)
I know that it should be fixed by using the IFERROR or IF(ISERROR function but I just can't seem to get it right.
Any help will be welcomed please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So use ifferror like this:

```
=iferror(IF($I$17>=$F18,IF(MOD(MONTH($I$17)-MONTH($F18),$D18)=0,$E18,0),0),"error")
```

You can replace error with blank or 0 as you wish

Comment: This suggestion was applied and it solved my problem